# How to Join User info to a Review Collection ? (Profile/Review case)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new in MongoDB and i'm trying to do a kind of "profile/reviews" module. I'm saving this two entities into two different collections because i read about some limitations of having a lot of nested elements (in this case, reviews will grow a lot).

My schemas are:

Review:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56073ea299f4ebd05df813a8"),
    "rate" : "0", 
    "owner" : "xub32YLjc4xJa38aM",
    "to" : "8zqCPbkwYMfajyFQx",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-27T00:56:02.328Z")
}
```

Where:

- **Rate**: Can be 0 or 1 (bad and good, simple)
- **Owner**: User ID who made the review
- **To**: Profile ID that was made a review

Profile:

```
{
    "_id" : "8zqCPbkwYMfajyFQx",
    "CI" : "19",
    "firstName" : "Alan",
    "lastName" : "Brito Delgado",
    "gender" : "m",
    "bio" : "lorem ipsum haha a bio right here pls",
    "birthdate" : ISODate("2015-09-26T01:54:46.687Z"),
    "specialty" : "Medico generalshhh",
    "worksIn" : "Integramedica",
    "academicInformation" : "Medicia UC 2010",
    "avatar_url" : "img/doctor-1.png",
    "certified" : false
}
```

Where: 
- **CI, Specialty, WorksIn, AcademicInformation and Certified** are the fields that i use to filter profiles

My problem is that i want to make a "Ranking view" where people can add filters to view a ranking based on their filters, and, i don't know how join information about the profile and the reviews count. (**Ranking is based on the count of good reviews**)

I have an approach of how to know the count of "good" reviews grouped by profile, but, i don't know how to append the "profile" information:

```
db.reviews.group({
  key: {to:1},
  cond: {rate:"1"},
  reduce: function(curr, result){
      result.count++;
  },
  initial: { count: 0 }
})
```

**EXAMPLE PROTOTYPE**
[image]

It's possible with my current model? or i need to nest profile with reviews or append user to review? (with this second approach, i think i will have user info not to date)

PS: I review Profiles, not users so, users are different than profiles

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus is, if you don't need to publish reactively, do the join on the client.  However, the point of meteor is to build reactive applications.

Have you looked at publish with relations?  https://github.com/svasva/meteor-publish-with-relations

You want something like:

```
Meteor.publish('rating', function(id) {
    Meteor.publishWithRelations({
      handle: this,
      collection: ratings,
      filter: id,
      mappings: [{
        key: '_id',
        collection: Meteor.profiles
      }, {
        reverse: true,
        key: '_id',
        collection: Comments,
        filter: { approved: true },
        options: {
          limit: 10,
          sort: { createdAt: -1 }
        },
        mappings: [{
          key: '_id',
          collection: Meteor.profiles
        }]
      }]
    });
  });
```

See also publish with reactions https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-publish

Finally, great resource for Meteor and an e-book worth buying https://www.discovermeteor.com/

ps - I assumed you wanted a Meteor answer given the tags. If you want pure mongodb then the above probably won't help you

Comment: I view the packages that you suggest, but the first, is 3 years old and doesn't seem like any activity in this 3 years so, i think it will not work ): (Reactive response is not necessary in this module) @brianlmerritt

Comment: Probably not good then :)  Have a look at http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb, also on github https://github.com/Elfoslav/meteor-join-collections

Comment: ps - sorry, am stuck for time now, but maybe set up a meteorpad? It's like a jsfiddle or codepen http://meteorpad.com/